# Docker images for armhf

Tags: robotic-arm, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi - I'm really excited to see the ROS Docker images! https://hub.docker.com/u/osrf/

The ROS images are currently based on the x86 ubuntu:trusty image. I see there's an osrf/ubuntu_armhf image, but are there any plans to provide ROS images that are armhf-based, in addition to x86?

I'm really interested in running ROS in Docker containers on Beaglebone Black, but need armhf-based images to do that.

Thanks,
Zach

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217249/docker-images-for-armhf/) by [zcox](https://answers.ros.org/users/18031/zcox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-09-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We would like to make them available. However we're using the dockerhub automated builds for easy of use and transparency, and the dockerhub servers do not support the armhf builds.  When and if dockerhub supports armhf we will plan to turn them on.

PS: We also have ROS images in the [ros organization](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/) on dockerhub too.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zcox](https://answers.ros.org/users/18031/zcox/) on 2015-09-12**:
That makes total sense, I hope they add armhf support soon. In the meantime, is it possible to build the ROS Docker images for armhf on our own infrastructure? Has anyone successfully built the images for armhf?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-09-12**:
Sure, we use them all the time for the armhf buildfarm. You can make your own, just replace the FROM line with [osrf/ubuntu_armhf](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrf/ubuntu_armhf/) in any Dockerfile which uses the default `ubuntu` base image.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-06-06**:
I believe these guys found a workaround that would allow us to build ARM containers on DockerHub: https://resin.io/blog/building-arm-containers-on-any-x86-machine-even-dockerhub

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update**: Support for ARM with ROS is now reflected in the Official DockerHub library!
You may find the public discourse announcement here:
[Announcing ROS Docker Images for ARM and Debian](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-ros-docker-images-for-arm-and-debian/2467)

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1